# TortoiseSVN from command line

Tags: java, svn, maven, tortoisesvn, release

We are building projects in a Subversion and Maven environment. My client forces me to use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) for accesing svn. Everything works fine but now I want to use `maven release:prepare` for creating a release version of my application. The trouble for me is that maven requires a subversion client which is callable via `svn`.

If I understands it right tortoise allows command line access only with tortoise.exe. Any idea how I tell maven to use tortoise instead of svn?

Unfortunately installing cygwin or any other svn client is not an option because of client's policies. :-(

Comment: Dilbert is getting more realistic as times goes by :)

Comment: there seems to be a javasvn provider for maven: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/maven-scm-provider-svnjava/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 1.7, TortoiseSVN includes a copy of the 1.7 SVN command line client in the TortoiseSVN/bin directory.

If using this version is also not an option, and the client doesn't want to let you install a command-line SVN client, explain us that this rule makes no sense because a command-line client is just another user interface over the same SVN library, and that if they insist, then you will lose a whole lot of time, and they will thus lose a whole lot of money, doing manually what could be automated.

Comment: Hurray! And I forget a last constraint. We are using tortoise 1.6.7. :-( But support thinks about upgrading. :-) So hapy waiting for new versions. Since others raised the answer up, I will accept it.